# how can my if statement not work even though I fill out the prompt() correct

Tags: javascript

So I am making a little rock, paper and scissors game in which you play VS the computer.

However, I made an `if` statement that should check whether you have filled out 'rock, paper or scissors'. If not, it should return an `alert()` that you did NOT fill out one of these 3, however when I do fill out rock, paper or scissors it still returns the `alert()`.

The function:

```
function rockPaperScissors() {
    let computerChoice;
    let loopFunction = false;
    let draw = 0;

    while (loopFunction === false) {
        let playerGuess = prompt('Enter rock, paper or scissors!');
        let computerChoiceCalculator = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

        if (playerGuess == '') {
            window.alert('ggggg');
            return;
        } else if (playerGuess != 'rock' || 'paper' || 'scissors') {
            window.alert('Please enter rock, paper or scissors');
        }
         else {
            if (computerChoiceCalculator <= 4) {
                computerChoice = 'rock';
                console.log(computerChoice);
            } else if (computerChoiceCalculator <= 7) {
                computerChoice = 'paper';
                console.log(computerChoice);
            } else {
                computerChoice = 'scissors';
                console.log(computerChoice);
            }

            if (playerGuess === computerChoice) {
                draw += 1;
                window.alert('THIS WAS A DRAW! THE COMPUTER HAD ' + computerChoice + ' AND U HAD ' + playerGuess);
            } else if (playerGuess === 'rock' && computerChoice === 'paper' || playerGuess === 'paper' && computerChoice === 'scissors' || playerGuess === 'scissors' && computerChoice === 'rock') {
                window.alert('The computer won this round! Lets try again! your try was ' + playerGuess + ' and the computer had ' + computerChoice);
            } else {
                window.alert('fuck yeah! u won!');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the code which causes the problem:

```
else if (playerGuess != 'rock' || 'paper' || 'scissors') {
   window.alert('Please enter rock, paper or scissors');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ohh this is wrong:

```
else if (playerGuess != 'rock' || 'paper' || 'scissors')
```

This conditional won't work because you can't group equality operators like this.

You have to make the comparison for each item. This conditional, as written, will always return true because `'paper'` will always be a truthy value.

You should do this instead:

```
else if (playerGuess != 'rock' && playerGuess != 'paper' && playerGuess != 'scissors')
```

Or you could do this, which is prettier:

```
else if (!['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'].includes(playerGuess))
```

Comment: Although I now see why it didn't work (thank you very much), why can't I use the pipes (OR) in this condition? Why am I forced to use the &&?

Comment: Because of how `OR` works. If you had `(playerGuess != 'rock' || playerGuess != 'paper' || playerGuess != 'scissors')` it would always be true because `playerGuess` could never be two things at once.

Comment: Be aware that `.includes` is not supported in IE. If you still want a shorter notation, you could use a regex instead: `!/^(rock|paper|scissors)$/.test(playerGuess)`

Answer (score 3):

you can't use this form of if statement `else if (playerGuess != 'rock' || 'paper' || 'scissors')`

it should be devided into three different comparasions like this:

```
else if (playerGuess != 'rock' && playerGuess != 'paper' && playerGuess != 'scissors')
```

Answer (score 1):

you should replace it with :

```
if (playerGuess != 'rock' && playerGuess != 'paper' && playerGuess != 'scissors') {
```

or

```
if(!['rock','paper','scissors'].includes(playerGuess))
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, `else if (playerGuess != 'rock' || 'paper' || 'scissors')` is incorrect syntax.

However, I think this syntax is probably the most modern and readable:

```
else if (!['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'].includes(playerGuess))
```